# Returning a lambda from a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I am trying to understand a very small piece of code which is taking a hell lot of time for me and I am still not clear how exactly it's working.

I know how `lambda` works and I have used them in the past, but this code is a bit complicated for me.

```
def demo(arg):
    return lambda target = None: (target, arg)

with_foo = demo({"foo": 50})
print with_foo()
print with_foo({"bar": 4})
```

The output of the above code is

```
(None, {'foo': 50})
({'bar': 4}, {'foo': 50})
```

Could someone explain to me how this `target` variable is populated and I get this output?

Comment: It may help if you re-write `demo` so that it creates a normal `def` function instead of a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def demo(arg):
    return lambda target = None: (target, arg)
```

This is equivalent to this code, not using `lambda`:

```
def demo(arg):
    def func(target=None):
        return (target, arg)
    return func
```

(Note that the `target = None` was just a parameter with a default value.)

So we have a function that returns another function.

When you do `with_foo = demo({"foo": 50})`, the result is a function equivalent to this:

```
def with_foo(target=None):
    return (target, {"foo": 50})
```

I hope that clears things up!

Comment: Thanks this really help me understand the first line of output, however I am still not able to understand the second output. When I call the second time like this `with_foo({"bar": 4})` the arg is `{"foo": 50}` and target contains `{"bar": 4}` could you please explain this

Comment: If you call `with_foo()`, `target` is `None`, so the result is `(None, {"foo": 50})`. If you call `with_foo({"bar": 4})`, then `target` is `{"bar": 4}`, so the result is `({"bar": 4}, {"foo": 50})`.

Comment: Thanks, it was a really great help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have after you executed the first 4 lines is equivalent to:

```
def with_foo(target=None):
    return target, {"foo":50}
```